Значение слова собирать
Собирать - это:
Сводить воедино, сосредотачивать, накапливать что-либо в каком-то месте

Собирать жильцов на обсуждение
Женщина собирала грибы

В каких предложениях значение слова соответствует данному?
Почему собирать жильцов в этом значении можно сказать, а собирать грибы нет?

Посмотрите толковый словарь, слово многозначное.  Приставка СО имеет значение соединения (грибов и жильцов) в один коллектив.// Собирать жильцов для обсуждения...  https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=собрать&mode=slovari&dicts[]=42


В толковом словаре Кузнецова указано 9 Значений для глагола собрать (нсв. собирать).

Практически во всех значениях глагол переходный, то есть требуется дополнение в форме  В.п. К данному вопросу подходят пункты 1 и 4.

Правильность и законченность суждения определяется по дополнительным распространителям, которые указаны в словаре.


Собрать людей (зачем?) на собрание, для обсуждения. Здесь указана цель.
Собрать грибы — набрать их в каком-то количестве. Здесь достаточно дополнения в В.п.
ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (о многозначных словах)
Существуют различные способы образования слов в русском языке. Один из них — лексико-семантический способ.
Лексико-семантический способ словообразования представляет собой распад значений многозначного слова. Значения слова расходятся по смыслу настолько далеко друг от друга, что образуют отдельные лексические единицы. Так в русском языке возникают омонимы: титан — гигант, вступивший в схватку с врагом;
титан — большой металлический бак для кипячения
воды;
титан — твердый металл.
  СОБРАТЬ, -беру, -берёшь; собрал, -ла, -ло; собранный; 
  -ран, -а и -а, -о; св. 1. кого (что). Объединить в одном 
   месте многих, созвав, пригласив и т.п. прийти, приехать и 
   т.п. с какой-л. целью. С. родственников, гостей. С. народ 
   на митинг. С. участников экскурсии на площади. С. 
   консилиум. С. совещание, военный совет, комиссию.  

   4. что (чего). Набрать в каком-л. количестве, сорвав с 
   ветки, срезав со стебля, подобрав с земли и т.п. С. 
   корзину ягод. С. много грибов. С. в лесу хворост, шишки. 
   С. лекарственные растения. С. огурцы с грядки. Картофель 
   собрали по пятьсот центнеров с гектара. С. большой урожай 
   (снять, убрать урожай с полей, огородов).


Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Брать - это переносить от одного к другому. То есть в отличие от взять, меняет принадлежность того, что взято. Бери эту вещь - то есть присвой, сделай своей, в отличие от возьми - временно подержи у себя. Родственный с корнями fer-ber, и вообще *bher Proto-Indo-European root meaning "to carry," also "to bear children."
Со- - приставка соединения, совмещения, объекдинения.
Собрать - взять что-то, физически или абстрактно, и объединить в одну группу по принципу.
Собрать жильцов - объединить людей по принципу "жилец", присвоить людям в этой группе название "жильцы на обсуждении".
Женщина собирала грибы - женщина присваивала грибы, делала их своей собственностью.
То есть со+брать - соединить+присвоить принадлежность к, отнести к.
Почему грибы не относятся к определению которое у тебя? Потому что не сказано куда женщина эти грибы переносит в реальности, то есть она их присваивает, но контекст присвоения опущен - кладёт ли она их в корзину или в передник, не известно. Поэтому "накапливать в каком-то месте" - не подходит. Вообще, и к первому тоже не подходит, потому что "накапливать в каком-то месте" - это to collect , "gather into one place or group" - "запасть в одном месте или группировать". Совсем другое слово, но лингвисты переводят все как "собирать", хотя to gather - это накапливать, то есть со смыслом "на потом", у собирать - нет смысла "накапливать на потом", потому что это немотивированный глагол.
Это ошибка составителей теста вообще.
То есть во второй фразе значение "накапливать", только потому, что "НА обсуждение". Это "НА" даёт изменения значения для всей ФРАЗЫ, а не для слова СОБИРАТЬ. То есть фраза имеет мотивацию, а глагол нет.
Можно попробовать обрубить "НА":

Мужчина собирал жильцов.

Женщина собирала грибы.


Как видно, фраза номер "1" теряет всякое содержание вообще, не ясно, о чём речь идёт. Кто такие "жильцы", это вообще люди, или мужчина заполнял камеры заключёнными? То есть в первой фразе вся семантика держится на "на собрание", сама же фраза без указания обстоятельства абсолютно пустая. А вот вторая фраза вполне самодостаточная. То есть к первой фразе определение к слову СОБИРАТЬ, данное составителями теста, относится ещё в меньшей степени, чем ко второй.
Вывод: определение в целом не верное.
Значит, это определение из словаря Кузнецова, откуда выросло это определение?

СБИРАТЬ или собирать, собрать, сбирывать что, сносить, свозить или
созывать в одно место; отыскивать и соединять, совокуплять, приобщать
одно к одному; скоплять. Даль.

Как видно. Даль первым словом пишет "СНОСИТЬ", то есть опять же СО-С + НЕСТИ. Даль допускает вольность, но однако не уходит от этимологии корня бер - носить, приносить.
Кузнецов же идёт дальше, и выходит совсем на другое слово:
Объединить в одном месте многих. Дело в том, что объединить - это глагол производный, а брать - это глагол непроизводный, наверное тут и начинается путаница.
Ну а составители вопроса шагают ещё дальше, утверждая что: "сосредотачивать"(от среда) и "накапливать что-либо в каком-то месте", - при том что Даль не писал что людей "накапливают" в одном месте, но созывают. Короче путаница глаголов с понятиями и приписывание им нехарактерных значений.
